# No builders are available to build a model

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

Gradle sync failed: No builders are available to build a model of type 'org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.internal.DummyModel'.
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (4 s 697 ms)

Comment: Hi Welcome. You should add some details on your question to get helpful answers. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have the same problem :/ Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Sneze If you've updated android studio or you've already have the latest version, open sdk manager and install `Android-SDK command line tools`

Comment: I resolved by following steps without losing the project. This will reset only your settings don't worry about the folder it will not cause any harm to your project. : Go to this location in your pc C:\Users[Username]

In this location you have noticed a direcctory call .AndroidStudio

Delete it.

Now your android studio is totally reset.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by following steps without losing the project. This will reset only your settings don't worry about the folder it will not cause any harm to your project. : Go to this location in your pc C:\Users[Username]

In this location you have noticed a direcctory call .AndroidStudio

Delete it.

Now your android studio is totally reset.